# React Native Unit Testing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, unit-testing, react-native-testing-library

I have a few questions about `react-native-testing-library`.

I want to implement unit tests on my app by using `react-native-testing-library`.

I run my `LoginScreen` component using the `render()` method and check the rendering status of any component from it.

Although it is not in my test class, it is stated that libraries such as `Redux`, `AsyncStorage`, `Messaging` etc. That I have used in `LoginScreen` should be mocked. An example test class;

```
describe('LoginScreen', () => {
  it('renders login form correctly', () => {
    const { getByTestId } = render(<LoginScreen />);

    // Check if necessary elements are rendered
    expect(getByTestId('loginButton')).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

My Mocks is;

```
/* eslint-disable no-undef */
import '@testing-library/jest-native/extend-expect';

jest.mock('@react-native-async-storage/async-storage', () =>
  require('@react-native-async-storage/async-storage/jest/async-storage-mock'),
);

jest.mock('@react-navigation/native', () => ({
  useNavigation: jest.fn(),
  useRoute: jest.fn(),
  useIsFocused: jest.fn(),
  useFocusEffect: jest.fn().mockImplementation(callback => callback()),
}));

jest.mock('@react-native-firebase/messaging', () => ({
  default: jest.fn(() => ({
    getToken: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve('mocked-token')),
    onMessage: jest.fn(),
    onNotificationOpenedApp: jest.fn(),
    onNotification: jest.fn(),
  })),
}));

jest.mock('react-native-device-info', () => ({
  getDeviceName: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve('mocked-device-name')),
  getDeviceId: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve('mocked-device-id')),
}));
```

I do not understand this. Why do I have to mock services like `Redux`, `AsyncStorage`, and `Messaging` even in any simple test? And after all these mockings, I get an error like this. I have no idea how to solve this;

```
  ● LoginScreen › renders login form correctly

    TypeError: (0 , _messaging.default) is not a function

       99 |
      100 |   const checkIfAppOpenedByNotification = async () => {
    > 101 |     await messaging()
          |                    ^
      102 |       .getInitialNotification()
      103 |       .then(async (remoteMessage: any) => {
      104 |         if (remoteMessage) {

      at src/screens/LoginScreen.tsx:101:20
      at asyncGeneratorStep (node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:3:24)
      at _next (node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:22:9)
      at node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:27:7
      at node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:19:12
      at apply (src/screens/LoginScreen.tsx:100:39)
      at checkIfAppOpenedByNotification (src/screens/LoginScreen.tsx:78:15)
      at asyncGeneratorStep (node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:3:24)
      at _next (node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:22:9)
      at node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:27:7
      at node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:19:12
      at apply (src/screens/LoginScreen.tsx:79:8)
```

Comment: Are you using RNFirebase?

Comment: Yes, im using RNFirebase messaging service

Comment: I was pretty sure about it. RNFirebase is a powerful tool to do many thing but it brings many issues like this.

Comment: Another thing. You asked two questions in one post. This is an anti-pattern on Stack Overflow. Because of this your post got two votes for being closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know, you are using RNFirebase messaging. For sure the post needs more details about installing `@react-native-firebase/messaging` and how you import and use the `messaging` function.

If your codes are based on docs and still the app is getting errors try to re-mock the `messaging` function by the following:

```js
jest.mock('../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/messaging', () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  default: () => Promise.resolve({}),
});
```

Comment: FAIL  __tests__/login.screen.test.js
  LoginScreen
    ✕ should render the LoginScreen component (35 ms)

  ● LoginScreen › should render the LoginScreen component

    Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

       7 | describe('LoginScreen', () => {
       8 |   it('should render the LoginScreen component', () => {
    >  9 |     const component = render(
         |                             ^
      10 |       <Provider store={store}>
      11 |         <LoginScreen />
      12 |       </Provider>,

Comment: I Have this problem, how can i fix?

Comment: Dear @mehmettalhairmak, This is not a standard action on Stack Overflow. If I were you, I would edit my question post to ask only ONE thing, and never ask a question in the comment side. If you believe my answer satisfied the last problem, Upvote me or check it as correct answer and then ask another question with a different post question.